# How can I do a bulk search to see if any of my photographs are used online without my permission?

Tags: search, internet

Can someone recommend a service or software that will help to search published photos online? I tried to do this with Google Image search but it requires a lot of time to upload images one by one. I'd like to check several photos at once, not one by one.

Comment: Service recommendations are off-topic here (as with almost all the Stack Exchange network).

Comment: What do you mean "published photos"? Are you trying to identify if _your_ photos have been used online without your permission, or something else?

Comment: mattdm, yet, exactly for this purpose!

Comment: @PhilipKendall except of course at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. Maybe close it here and migrate/re-ask there?

Comment: ok,I will, sorry.

Comment: Sorry again, did not find how to close it - it seems it'll be closed automatically in 5 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are tired with searching your image publications in the Internet by uploading them to Google Search one by one, you can check out Daminion photo manager. It allows you to search images in the Internet in batch:

[image]

PS. I work at Daminion Software.